# Laravel condition inside count

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting "Unknown column 'month'".

```
$result = DB::table('project')
        ->select(array(
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M") as month'),
            DB::raw('count(case when DATE_FORMAT(finish_time,"%M") = month then 1 else null end) as finished')
        ))
        ->orderBy('start_time', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get();
```

Comment: You can't use column aliases before or within a group. You'll have to use the full column calculation instead.

Comment: :(. How I can go around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use month in case as you defined in query like synonym. Try it like this:

```
$result = DB::table('project')
    ->select(array(
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M") as month'),
        DB::raw('count(case when DATE_FORMAT(finish_time,"%M") = DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M") then 1 else null end) as finished')
    ))
    ->orderBy('start_time', 'ASC')
    ->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M")')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm already tried, no luck.I fink I need 2 querys.

Comment: still the same error?

Comment: groupBy gives me ERROR "Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M")'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DB::Raw in group by as well. just check below code.

```
   $result = DB::table('project')
        ->select(array(
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M") as month'),
            DB::raw('count(case when DATE_FORMAT(finish_time,"%M") = DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M") then 1 else null end) as finished')
        ))
        ->orderBy('start_time', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy(DB::Raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%M")')) // here you have to use DB::Raw()
        ->get();
```